# Delete Rows based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I delete rows based on just two column conditions.

Example

```
Table 1

id  name  phone
1   aa    123
1   aa    345
1   bb    123
2   aa    456
1   NULL  123
1         123
```

My Expected output

```
id name phone 
1  bb   123
2  aa   456
```

My condition to delete: if id and name is same, delete the rows
If one of the value in a condition is null or blank it should also delete the row as given in the input.

Comment: Which row would you want to keep, the one with phone 123 or 345?

Comment: I want to delete both the rows if id and name are the same

Comment: Please post your table layouts, and what you have tried here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Please revise your question to provide a bit more clarity as your comment "if id and name are the same" - they will never be the same in your example data since one is a number and the other a string value for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete from table1 t where exists (
Select * from 
(Select id, name from table1 group by id, name having count(*) > 1) t2 where t.id = t2.id and t.name = t2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  You can do the select first for testing purposes, then remove the Select and uncomment out the delete.

```
-- This joins on the table the set of data that has more then 1 row with duplicate IDs, and names.  Then you can delete from here.
    --DELETE t1
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN (
        -- this gets all the records that have more then 1 ID and Name that are the same.
        SELECT ID, name
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY ID, name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) ToDelete ON T1.ID = ToDelete.ID
    AND T1.name = ToDelete.name
```

Comment: Sure, Let me try. Thanks

Comment: If the NAME is either blank or null with same ID. Will the query still capture it? @Brad

Comment: NULL is handled weird.  Maybe change the spots where NAME is to ISNULL(name, '')

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tablea (
    id int,
    name varchar(3),
    phone int
)

insert into #tablea (id, name, phone)
values
    (1,'aa','123'),
    (1,'aa','345'),
    (1,'bb','123'),
    (2,'aa','456')

select * from #tablea

delete a
from #tablea a
inner join (
    select id, name
    from #tablea
    group by id, name
    having COUNT(*) > 1
) b on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name

select * from #tablea

drop table #tablea
```